# How to bind "mobileinit" event in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

This is how I'm trying to hook into the mobileinit event:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    console.log("Mobile init");
});
```

But this doesn't work on Chrome (Latest version), Ripple v0.9.1 and on a BlackBerry bold 9790 running OS7.0.

Note: I also tried using `.on()` instead of `.bind()` but no luck. Both jQuery mobile versions (1.0.1 and 1.1.0) failed.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I've used this and it *does* work.

Is it possible something else is breaking the script or the mobileinit isn't being fired?

Does Chrome fire mobileinit?

I just found some code I used in jQuery Mobile 1.0 and we just upgraded to 1.1.0 and it works.

You're making sure to also include regular ol' jQuery, right?

[jQueryMobile's docs do it](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/globalconfig.html), so I'm sure it works. Something else must be wrong. Sorry I'm not much help. Do you have any more info? Or try with a different device.

**[edit]** On that same self page, it says "Because the mobileinit event is triggered immediately, you'll need to bind your event handler before jQuery Mobile is loaded. Link to your JavaScript files in the following order:"

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script> <!-- Note your script before jqm -->
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Looks like the script order can matter.

Comment: And that `custom-scripting.js` file would store your `mobileinit` event handler so it is bound by the time jQuery Mobile initializes (and fires the `mobileinit` event).

Comment: I knew this, having read it in the docs, but it still caught me out.  Thankyou for this post.  Saved me hours!

Comment: @DaveR I know this is a total aside, but I haven't worked with jQuery Mobile much since April and the same day you comment, I am working on compiling an app with PhoneGap done in jQM. Anyway, glad I could help!

Answer (score 5):

Here is another simple example that works with me (for android and ios)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/resources/lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.2.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function()
                 {
                 if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("android") != -1)
                 {
                 // your logic here
                 $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
                 $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
                 }
                 if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") != -1)
                 {
                 // your logic here
                 $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
                 $.support.cors = true;
                 }
                 });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="files/resources/lib/jquerymobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
```

1. include the main jquery file
2. bind mobileinit before jquery mobile
3. include jquery mobile js file