# Phonegap windows phone ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, windows-phone-7, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am going to lose my hair on that
I have built a simple app that works great on IOS and Android but all ajax calls are failing
I have tried lots of mojo jojo tricks , different versions of cordova but nothing helps

My code looks like

```
$("#twitter").live('pageshow', function() {

    // Empty the list of recorded tracks
    $("#tweets_list").empty();


    var tmpTweet = "";

    //regex for urls
    var output = $("#tweets_list");
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/mysecretathens.json?count=20&_nocache=" + cacheBuster,

        jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
        timeout: 5000,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loader').show();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#loader').hide();
        },
        success: function(data, status) {
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                var tmpTweet = item.text;
                //replace links
                tmpTweet = item.text.replace(/(http:\/\/\S+)/g, "<a href='$1'>$1</a>");

                var singleTweet = "<li class='twitter-feed'>" + item.text + "</li>";

                output.append(singleTweet).listview('refresh');
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            output.text('There was an error loading the data.');
        }
    });
    $("#tweets_list").listview('refresh');



});​
```

I have placed S.support.cors= true;
and $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages= true and also tried several other tricks

The only approach that worked was Simon's [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8924482/phonegap-jquery-ajax-request-does-not-work)
But I would like to use my original code, I am currently using Cordova 2.0.0
and windows phone sdk 7.1 on visual studio

Comment: I demoed a WP7 PhoneGap Twitter search app in a talk a while back. The sourcecode is available here: http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/slides-and-code-from-my-wpug-talk-on-phonegap/ - this might help you.

Comment: im gonna follow you lolz

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions:

1. Have you confirmed what error you're getting from the AJAX calls? (eg examining the response with Fiddler, for example)
2. Have you confirmed the JqueryMobile mobileinit event is firing?  A simple console.log should suffice.  The order you specify your script tags is *very* important.  See this post.
   [How to bind "mobileinit" event in jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214083/how-to-bind-mobileinit-event-in-jquery-mobile/10214362#comment17013914_10214362)