# Unable to customize Loader in jQuery Mobile 1.3.1

Tags: jquery-mobile, loader

I have used the standard approach to customize the default text for the Loader in jQuery Mobile 1.3.1:

```
$(document).on("mobileinit", function () {
   $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.options.hidePlaceholderMenuItems = true;
   $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.text = "Loading...";
   $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.textVisible = true;
   $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.theme = "a";
   $.mobile.loader.prototype.options.html = "";
});
```

This does not result in a custom loader showing the text 'Loading...'.

Comment: have you placed that code in `head` after jquery and before jquery mobile?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/d39FX/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind "mobileinit" event in jQuery Mobile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214083/how-to-bind-mobileinit-event-in-jquery-mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to put this code in a separate file and load it after Jquery and before JQM.  Simply putting the script in between in  tags did not solve the issue.